# Javascript: Asynchronous function confusion

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, node-mysql

I have a function which calls an asynchronous function (`connection.query`), I want to modify the parameter `comment` and store the modified value in variable `res` and return it. However the problem is that the return statement is being executed before the `forEach` finishes, inside of which there's an asynchronous function. How do I ensure that the two statements `console.log("outside:" + res);` and `return res;` happen ONLY after everything above it is done executing.

```
var res = "";


function testComment(comment) {
    var words = comment.split(" ");
    words.forEach(function(word, i){
        (function(index){
            connection.query('select good_words from words where bad_words = ' + connection.escape(word), function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                }
                if(result.length != 0){
                    this.res = comment.replace(word, result[0].good_words);
                    console.log("inside:" + this.res);
                }
            });
        })(i);
    });
    console.log("outside:" + this.res);
    return this.res;
}
```

I tried doing this, I created a second function which returns the value `res` like so,

```
function callback(){
   return res;
}
```

and I modified `testComment` to accept a callback and then return it like this,

```
function testComment(comment, callback){
  ..all the working..(forEach loop which has a asyn function in it)
  return callback();
}
```

But here the problem is that `testComment` would return the `callback()` before `forEach` finishes, this is really confusing me. Any way to fix this?

EDIT : For more context, this is what the function does, 
I have a table in a database which has a list of `bad_words` and a list of `good_words` which replace these `bad_words` in the input string (`comments` in this case). The parameter `comment` is to be tested for the `bad_words` and replaced by the corresponding `good_words`.

Comment: try using the normal for loop: 

//this loop is sync in nature 
for(var i=0,len=words.length; i<len;i++){
   var word = words[i];
   //the code what you want to do.....  
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
var wordsProcessed = 0;
(function(index){
    connection.query('select good_words from words where bad_words = ' + connection.escape(word), function(err, result){
        wordsProcessed++;
        if(err){                 
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        if(result.length != 0){
            this.res = comment.replace(word, result[0].good_words);
            console.log("inside:" + this.res);
        }
        if(wordsProcessed >= words.length){
            //THIS IS WHERE YOU RETURN YOUR RES
        }
    });
})(i);
```

Or more conveniently, you should use bluebird :)

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var promiseArray = words.map(function(word){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        connection.query('select good_words from words where bad_words = ' + connection.escape(word), function(err, result){
            if(err) reject(err);
            else resolve(result);
        }); 
    });
});

Promise.all(promiseArray).then(function(result){
    return this.res;
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir, you saved my life!